# Python request returning IN-QUEUE status after posting

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been trying to learn and understand how http requests are being made between the clients and server, so I've decided to test out by sending a simple post request to [geeksforgeeks'](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/) online IDE. Using requests, I am able to get a response of the following,
`{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'sid': 'df1acaffefacb25dfef2c7cf66022925'}` using the following code,

```
import requests
import time
url = "https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/main.php"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'}

code = """
print("hello")
"""

data = {
    'lang':'Python3',
    'code': code,
    'input':'0',
    'save':'false'
}

r = requests.post(url, data = data, headers = headers)
print(r.json())
```

Next, I know that i have to resend back the `sid` parameter to https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/submissionResult.php in order to get a successful response. However, when i entered the following code,

```
requesttype = {
    'sid': r.json()['sid'] ,
    'requestType': 'fetchResults'
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'}

url2 = "https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/submissionResult.php"

session = requests.Session()
outcome = session.post(url2, data = requesttype, headers = headers)
```

It returns `{'status': 'IN-QUEUE'}`. Upon analyzing the `networks` tab in my browser, it seems as though the online IDE has a queue system that will only parse your incoming request server sided through a queue-like system. Hence I would like to know how to obtain a success response by "communicating" with their queue system.

A successful response looks like this,

```
{"valid":"1","output":"testing\n","time":"0.02","compResult":"S","memory":"0.125","hash":"79c7a40c6f6b36f1dfc23119f27ba66e_Tester_U16","status":"SUCCESS"}
```

My *hunch* is telling me that the website is detecting me as a bot and I should use something else like selenium perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code on my computer, it works just fine. I believe the problem could be something to do with the SSL certificate that you might want to initialize.

Comment: Is it possible to show the exact steps you took to obtain the results?

Comment: When pasting in the exact code given in the answer, It worked just fine. I am saying that there could be a difference on your end.

Comment: Im not quite sure if i am understanding you right. Are you saying that you managed to get a response that looks like this? `{"valid":"1","output":"testing\n","time":"0.02","compResult":"S","memory":"0.125","hash":"79c7a40c6f6b36f1dfc23119f27ba66e_Tester_U16","status":"SUCCESS"}`